# If $f$ is the uniform limit of a bounded sequence on Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$, must $f$ be Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assume that $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of Riemann integrable functions, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a, b]$.  Is $f$ Riemann integrable?  Why?

Comment: Assume that you ask a basic integration exercise on MSE. Is it better to include in the question your thoughts about the problem? Why?

Comment: Note that, uniform convergence preserves Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) There exists $\,M\in\Bbb R\,$ s.t.

$$|f_n(x)|\le M\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in[a,b]\,\,\wedge\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

2) Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence theorem.